# Unable to access variable outside of for loop

Tags: php

I am getting some exchange rate data and would like to access the variable outside of the for loop. My current code only results in:

1: 0.82910

but my expected result is:

1: 0.82910

2: 0.82910

I am wondering why this variable is not accessible outside of the loop and how can I make it accessible?

My code (Sorry if the code is bad, Im new to PHP)

```
$vExchaRates = file_get_contents("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");

$xml = simplexml_load_string($vExchaRates);

for ($i = 1; $i <= 32; $i++) {
    if ($xml->Cube[0]->Cube[0]->Cube[$i]->attributes()->currency == "GBP") {
        $vGBPERate = $xml->Cube[0]->Cube[0]->Cube[$i]->attributes()->rate;
        echo "1: " . $vGBPERate . "\r\n";
    }
}

echo "2: " . $vGBPERate;
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: no errors? it doesn't look like your code is even reaching the other side of the loop if you don't even see "2: "

Comment: What happens if you add `. "\r\n"` to the second `echo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if object `$xml->Cube[0]->Cube[0]->Cube[$i]` isset or not.

```
$vExchaRates = file_get_contents("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($vExchaRates);

for ($i = 1; $i <= 32; $i++) {
    if (isset($xml->Cube[0]->Cube[0]->Cube[$i]) && $xml->Cube[0]->Cube[0]->Cube[$i]->attributes()->currency == "GBP") {
        $vGBPERate = $xml->Cube[0]->Cube[0]->Cube[$i]->attributes()->rate;
        echo "1: " . $vGBPERate . "\r\n";
   }
}    
echo "2: " . $vGBPERate;
```

**[Demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GZEG0i)**

**Note:** Turn on your errors using `ini_set("display_errors",1)` to get such errors or notices.

Comment: +1. Probably the errors is turned off, and he just see first echo.

Comment: This has worked, I will accept this answer :) Thank You for your help. This is hosted php so I am unable to edit the php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the 32 was too large and number and is throwing it off.  It might be better to use foreach instead.  It works perfectly:

```
$vExchaRates = file_get_contents("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");

$xml = simplexml_load_string($vExchaRates);

foreach($xml->Cube[0]->Cube[0]->Cube as $a)
{

    if ($a->attributes()->currency == "GBP") {
        $vGBPERate = $a->attributes()->rate;
        echo "1: " . $vGBPERate . "\r\n";
}
}

echo "2: " . $vGBPERate;
```